# Does IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: mean the file hasn't been written?

Tags: json, python-2.7, csv, tweepy

I'm using Tweepy for the first time. Currently getting this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-cdd7ebe0c00f> in <module>()
----> 1 data_json = io.open('raw_tweets.json', mode='r', encoding='utf-8').read() #reads in the JSON file
      2 data_python = json.loads(data_json)
      3 
      4 csv_out = io.open('tweets_out_utf8.csv', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') #opens csv file

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'raw_tweets.json'
```

I've got a feeling that the code I've got isn't working. For example print(status) doesn't print anything. Also I see no saved CSV or JSON file in the directory.

I'm a newbie so any help/documentation you can offer would be great!

```
import time
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import os
import json
import csv
import io
from pymongo import MongoClient

ckey = 'blah'
consumer_secret = 'blah'
access_token_key = 'blah'
access_token_secret = 'blah'


#start_time = time.time() #grabs the system time
keyword_list = ['keyword'] #track list

#Listener Class Override
class listener(StreamListener):

    def __init__(self, start_time, time_limit=60):

        self.time = start_time
        self.limit = time_limit
        self.tweet_data = []

    def on_data(self, data):

        saveFile = io.open('raw_tweets.json', 'a', encoding='utf-8')

        while (time.time() - self.time) < self.limit:

            try:

                self.tweet_data.append(data)

                return True


            except BaseException, e:
                print 'failed ondata,', str(e)
                time.sleep(5)
                pass

        saveFile = io.open('raw_tweets.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
        saveFile.write(u'[\n')
        saveFile.write(','.join(self.tweet_data))
        saveFile.write(u'\n]')
        saveFile.close()
        exit()

    def on_error(self, status):

        print status

class listener(StreamListener):
    def __init__(self, start_time, time_limit=10):

        self.time = start_time
        self.limit = time_limit

    def on_data(self, data):

        while (time.time() - self.time) <  self.limit:
            print(data)
            try:


                client = MongoClient('blah', 27017)
                db = client['blah']
                collection = db['blah']
                tweet = json.loads(data)

                collection.insert(tweet)

                return True


            except BaseException as e:
                print('failed ondata,') 
                print(str(e))
                time.sleep(5)
                pass

        exit()

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
data_json = io.open('raw_tweets.json', mode='r', encoding='utf-8').read() #reads in the JSON file
data_python = json.loads(data_json)

csv_out = io.open('tweets_out_utf8.csv', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') #opens csv file
```

UPDATED: Creates file but file is empty

```
import tweepy
import datetime
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('xxx', 'xxx')
auth.set_access_token('xxx', 'xxx')


class listener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def __init__(self, timeout, file_name, *args, **kwargs):

        super(listener, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.start_time = None
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.tweet_data = []

    def on_data(self, data):
        if self.start_time is None:
            self.start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        while (datetime.datetime.now() - self.start_time).seconds < self.timeout:
            with open(self.file_name, 'a') as data_file:
                data_file.write('\n')
                data_file.write(data)

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status


l = listener(60, 'stack_raw_tweets.json')
mstream = tweepy.Stream(auth=auth, listener=l)
mstream.filter(track=['python'], async=True)
```

Comment: 1. Can you try with the full path to 'raw_tweets.json' while writing as well are reading why do you have two class with same name.

Comment: Your classes do not do anything unless they are instantiated and registered as a handler somewhere.

Comment: @Akilesh Tried full path with no success :( Could you suggest where/how I'd put a handler in?

Comment: Error means that raw_tweets.json is not available in working dir. Try checking `os.getcwd()` to see where files are located or use absolute file path instead of file name.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski what output should I expect from os.getcwd()? I ran it at the bottom of the script and got nothing back?

Comment: @NickDuddy likely you want to `print` it. What you want it to be is a directory where `raw_tweets.json` is located. What it will be - another dir.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski did print(os.getcwd) got nothing back, not even an error.

Comment: @NickDuddy it's not supposed to throw error, it should [return a string representing the current working directory](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getcwd). It's impossible for this function to return nothing.

Comment: @NickDuddy your file is empty because you have not created any stream for your listener to be called from. Check the last two lines of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are not creating a Stream for the listener. The last but one line of the code below does that. Followed by that you have to start the Stream, which is the last line. I must warn you that storing this in mongodb is the right thing to do as the file that I am storing it seems to grow easily to several GB. Also the file is not exactly a json. Each line in the file is a json. You must tweak it to your needs.

```
import tweepy
import datetime
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)


class listener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def __init__(self, timeout, file_name, *args, **kwargs):

        super(listener, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.start_time = None
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.tweet_data = []

    def on_data(self, data):
        if self.start_time is None:
            self.start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        while (datetime.datetime.now() - self.start_time).seconds < self.timeout:
            with open(self.file_name, 'a') as data_file:
                data_file.write('\n')
                data_file.write(data)

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status


l = listener(60, 'raw_tweets.json')
mstream = tweepy.Stream(auth=auth, listener=l)
mstream.filter(track=['python'], async=True)
```

Comment: On a positive note, it created the JSON file. However it was empty and I got the following error message.

Exception in thread Thread-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 294, in _run
    raise exception
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))

Comment: Are you using exactly the same code that I posted? Can you edit your original post and put your new code. The Connection aborted could mean you lost your internet connection when tweepy was streaming data, but your json file should have had some data.

Comment: I've updated the post. I've also ran it a couple of times to check, def doesn't populate.